# For loop and plotting in R

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

The program is a simple epidemic simulator which is mostly done, except for one thing. I'd like to get the number of infected per time-step on a plot (it could be any type of plot, most preferable would be a line graph).

Here's the crucial part of the entire script:

```
 for (i in 1:simlength) {
  discordant.links <- which(infected[links[,1]]+infected[links[,2]]==1)
  transmit <- rbinom(length(discordant.links),1,p.t)
  transmitter.links <- discordant.links[transmit==1]
  nodes.of.transmitter.links <-   unique(as.vector(links[transmitter.links,1:2]))
  infected[nodes.of.transmitter.links] <- 1
  infected[infected==1] <- sample(c(1,2),length(infected[infected==1]),replace=TRUE,prob=c(1-p.r,p.r))
  if (plot.spread) {
    node.colour[infected==1] <- "red"
    node.colour[infected==2] <- "green"
    plot(network.i,layout=fixlayout, main=paste("Time =", i), vertex.color=node.colour)
 }
}
```

This draws me a graph about how the infection spreads within the network. `simlength` is the total number of time-steps.

I'd like to modify this algorithm in a way that it gives me the total number of infected per each time-step. Note that the red nodes (`[infected==1]`) are the infected individuals within the population.

Comment: It would certainly help if your example was [self-contained](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `ninfected <- rep(NA, simlength)` at the beginning, then `ninfected[i] <- sum(infected==1)` once you define infection ... might this be what you're hoping for?

Comment: This could be, however I need to get a plot. I should have given a better example... I'd like to get a plot which would show how many people are infected at each time step. For example if simlength == 5, then I could get a plot which shows the total number of infected people at each time step, which are in this case: 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 and 5. Like at time step 1 there are 10 infected, at time step 2 there are 25 infected and etc.. Sorry, that I'm being an unprofessional, but I'm still rather new at this.